# How to perform double include on two levels of depth?

Tags: c#, linq, include

I'm including stuff as follows.

```
List<Donkey> donkeys = context.Donkeys
  .Include(donkey => donkey.Monkey)
  .ToList();
```

Of course, each monkey has a pointer to its donkey. However, I just noticed that there's some wonkies too and each wonkey points to its monkey. How should I perform the extra include in such case?

```
List<Donkey> donkeys = context.Donkeys
  .Include(donkey => donkey.Monkey)
  .Include(donkey => donkey.Monkies.Wonkies)
  .ToList();
```

The above won't work because monkies don't know of wonkies. It's a bit surprising because if we look up the monkies, we can include the wonkies into them... So I'm fairly certain I just got the syntax wrongly.

Is there syntax that would allow me to bring the wonkies into this picture anyway? Googling gave nothing but it could be because I can't really describe it well enough.

Comment: How are you using Include.  Include is part of System.Data.Object.Object() which is a part of a database.  It looks like Donkeys is a DataSet, Monkey is a DataTable, and Wonkies is a column in the DataTable.  So the return object is a List<string> not List<Donkey>.

Comment: How do you figure? All three are in fact tables (or views).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
List<Donkey> donkeys = context.Donkeys
  .Include(donkey => donkey.Monkies)
  .Include(donkey => donkey.Monkies.Select(monkey => monkey.Wonkies))
  .ToList();
```

or

```
List<Donkey> donkeys = context.Donkeys
  .Include("Monkey")
  .Include("Monkey.Wonkey")
  .ToList();
```

Comment: Did you know the answer or did you gogle? If you googled, how dod you find it? What were the serach keys?

Comment: If you play ef and linq a lot, then you will know.

Comment: The latter example is for EF 4, right? It still works in EF 6 but the first syntax is preferred, isn't it?

Comment: yes, when there is not such lambda expression for include.

Comment: yes, as if the table change first syntax result build error, second would only give you error runtime.